# Are Authenticated Encryption ciphersuites supported in legacy TLS versions older than TLS 1.2?

Tags: tls, authenticated-encryption, openssl, gcm, chacha

I have read in a paper that Authenticated Encryption (by this I mean those that support GCM mode or ChaCha20 ciphers) are not supported in versions older than TLS 1.2?

I could not confirm this as the paper does not provide a reference. Can any expert confirm this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure AES GCM is only defined for TLS 1.2.  If you look at [RFC 5288](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288), it's titled "AES Galois Counter Mode (GCM) Cipher Suites for TLS" and it only defines suites for TLS 1.2:

> The following cipher suites use the new authenticated encryption
> modes defined in TLS 1.2 with AES in Galois Counter Mode (GCM)

Later on it says

> These cipher suites make use of the authenticated encryption with
> additional data defined in TLS 1.2 [RFC5246].  They MUST NOT be
> negotiated in older versions of TLS.  Clients MUST NOT offer these
> cipher suites if they do not offer TLS 1.2 or later.  Servers that
> select an earlier version of TLS MUST NOT select one of these cipher
> suites.

While this doesn't mean that a different, particularly a later, RFC couldn't have defined them, I can't see why one would have done so.

Comment: [rfc7905](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7905)

Comment: Thanks. For readers: ChaCha20 is supported in TLS 1.2 and later.